# What is the name for the sliding doors made of a wood frame with paper?

Tags: word-requests

I can't find the word for what these sliding doors are called. I seem to remember shoji. Thank you.

Comment: Simply searching 'Japanese sliding doors' on Google gets https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sh%C5%8Dji as the first result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Wikipedia

> In traditional Japanese architecture, a shōji (障子) is a door, window or room divider consisting of translucent paper over a frame of wood which holds together a lattice of wood or bamboo. While washi is the traditional paper, shōji may be made of paper made by modern manufacturing processes; plastic is also in use.

I will just include the picture from the page while I am at it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to know a name of a Japanese-style room's door:

[image: Shoji]

<sup>This is a free picture. You can download from [here](https://www.pakutaso.com/20150232044post-5173.html).</sup>
The name is [障子]{しょうじ}.

---

[Wikipedia (Japanese)](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9A%9C%E5%AD%90)

> 障子{しょうじ}は、日本家屋における扉、窓に用いる建具の一つで、明かりを通すように木枠に紙張りになっているものは明障子{あかりしょうじ}ともいう。

Shoji is used in doors and widows in Japanese-house. Shoji that's put papers on wood frame in such a way as to allow light to pass through is called [明障子]{あかりしょうじ}.